# How to use gettext and settext

Tags: java

So I have 2 different panels, the first panel works like it should but the Actionlistener might be needed to solve my issue:

```
class knopHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed ( ActionEvent e )
    {
        JFrame frame2 = new JFrame ( "Total Hours" );
        frame2.setSize ( 600, 500 );
        JPanel uitvoerpanel = new uitvoerpanel();
        frame2.setContentPane( uitvoerpanel );
        frame2.setVisible( true );
        frame1.setVisible( false );

        String invoerstring1 = maandaginvoer.getText();
        int getal1 = Integer.parseInt( invoerstring1 );

        String invoerstring2 = dinsdaginvoer.getText();
        int getal2 = Integer.parseInt( invoerstring2 );

        String invoerstring3 = woensdaginvoer.getText();
        int getal3 = Integer.parseInt( invoerstring3 );

        String invoerstring4 = donderdaginvoer.getText();
        int getal4 = Integer.parseInt( invoerstring4 );

        String invoerstring5 = vrijdaginvoer.getText();
        int getal5 = Integer.parseInt( invoerstring5 );

        String invoerstring6 = zaterdaginvoer.getText();
        int getal6 = Integer.parseInt( invoerstring6 );

        String invoerstring7 = zondaginvoer.getText();
        int getal7 = Integer.parseInt( invoerstring7 );

        int resultaat = getal1 + getal2 + getal3 + getal4 + getal5 + getal6 + getal7;   

    } 
}
```

The relevant part of the second panel looks like this :

```
public uitvoerpanel()
{
setLayout( null );

naamvak = new JTextField ( 20 );
naamvak.setHorizontalAlignment ( JTextField.LEFT );
naamvak.setEditable ( false );
naamvak.setText( naaminvoer.getText() );

badgevak = new JTextField ( 20 );
badgevak.setHorizontalAlignment ( JTextField.LEFT );
badgevak.setEditable ( false );
badgevak.setText( badgeinvoer.getText() ) ;

totaalurenvak = new JTextField ( 20 );
totaalurenvak.setHorizontalAlignment ( JTextField.LEFT );
totaalurenvak.setEditable ( false );
totaalurenvak.setText( "" + resultaat );
```

The first panel has a few textfields where people can type something, I want the text from those textfields to appear in the textfields in the second panel but I am at a loss. When I run the program now nothing appears in the textfields in the second panel.

The "int resultaat" from the actionlistener should also appear in one of the textfields but I have also not been able to get this to work.

Am I putting the setter/getter in the right place or should this be in the actionlistener for example? Or am I missing a different piece of code?

Comment: The question is too broad. Please, consider changing it and provide a minimal example.

Comment: I understand, but I have no idea where in the code I need to be really so I guess that's why I did it like this.. :( I'm hoping someone can still help me.

Comment: Provide a [mcve] please. It is simple to post a complete code here, but it is not easy for us to find what you want.

Comment: Edited to hopefully be more clear now..

Comment: Do you want to display the text in other panel on the click of a button? Or as the user types?

Comment: on the click of a button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event handling with Action Listeners in Swing is straightforward.

As mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html), you need to perform the following steps:

> 1. Declare an event handler class and specify that the class either
>      implements an ActionListener interface or extends a class that
>      implements an ActionListener interface. For example: 
>       `public class MyClass implements ActionListener {`
> 2. Register an instance of the event
>      handler class as a listener on one or more components. For example:
>      `someComponent.addActionListener(instanceOfMyClass);`
> 3. Include code that
>      implements the methods in listener interface. For example: 
>      `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
>      ...//code that reacts to the action...  }`

I see that you are already trying to do some of these.

The problem in your method is that you cannot have an action listener on a panel which is a container of components. You need to define your action listener for individual components e.g. in your case, the text field `maandaginvoer`. You need to register (step 2) your listener with the text field on the panel 1.

Once you fix this problem, you should be able to see your desired output.

Comment: Thanks VHS aswell! Gonna try this now!

Comment: It worked, thanks for your explanation.. been struggling with this all day for school so you have no idea how much I appreciate it! thanks again!

Comment: @StefanBuijs. You are welcome. I am glad that I could help the community.

Comment: Sadly doesn't work for the `totaalurenvak` which needs to add up different numbers from `maandaginvoer` `dinsdaginvoer` and so on. I have this: `totaalurenvak.setText ( "" + resultaat );` but the compiler tells me I'm missing a symbol. I guess the problem is with something else but figured I would ask anyway. Guess I still have some stuff to sort out.

Comment: @StefanBuijs try parsing the getText() result to Int. getText() method returns the string.

Comment: I tried `totaalurenvak.setText ( Integer.parseInt ( resultaat ));` but the compiler still tells me ''error: cannot find symbol''. I also tried `totaalurenvak.setText ( Integer.toString ( resultaat) );`

Comment: @StefenBuijs try resultaat=Integer.parseInt(yourtextfield.getText()); Then totaalurenvak.setText(Integer.toString(resultaat));

Comment: Thank you for your help but it's not working. I'll keep trying.

Answer (score 2):

Say, your button is *jButton1* and your textFields are *jTextField1* and *jTextField2*

Add an actionListner for your button as:

```
jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
```

---

Then simply implement this method:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        String s=jTextField1.getText();
        jTextField2.setText(s);
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean with InitComponents or initblock.. only been learning java for a few weeks.. I'm gonna go ahead and try a few different places with your suggestion anyway, thanks for the help either way!

Comment: @StefanBuijs I have already edited the answer. I stupidly assumed that you were using an IDE(Don't know why!). But still you can simply register your components and implement some action just the way I have shown.